# Finding out paths in a graph of 175K nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, dijkstra

I am facing a problem in big data analysis, where I am finding out paths using Dijkstras algorithm for a graph with more than 175K nodes. But the problem is that I do not know for a particular source and destination if a path exists or not. I have to do this for about 1000 sources and destinations. But I cannot pick them randomly, as I am not sure if a path exists between them or not. I am not sure how to handle this. One execution of algorithm in MapReduce enviorment take about 15 mins time locally. So, trial and error is not an option. Only we I can find about at least 1000 sources and destinations is to find cycles(?) or strongly connected components? Is this correct ? I hope my problem is clear to understand.

I am basically looking for finding say 1000 pairs of sources and destinations for which a path exists in a graph of that size

Comment: So are you looking for a method to find if node `dest` is reachable from node `src`?

Comment: I am basically looking for finding say 1000 pairs of sources and destinations for which a path exists in a graph of that size

Comment: Any constraints on these pairs?  Or can they be completely arbitrary?

Comment: can you show us what you did with mapreduce?

Comment: @SamMussmann No constraint as such..

Comment: @Aptem : I am trying to run mapreduce job executing dijkstras algorithm for a particular source to destination. But it is for 'A Source' and 'A Destination', I have found a way to do this for N sources and destination but I am not clear how should I chose those pairs of sources and destinations?

Comment: @AK: if there are really no constraints, why not pick one thousand adjacent pairs? I guess you really do have some constraint that the thousand are a 'representative' sample in some sense. It would be best to be precise as possible about your required characteristics, as any solution to your problem is likely to be heuristic.

Comment: I think 175k vertices can be handled easily by igraph (http://igraph.sf.net), so you might just switch to that. It depends on the density of the graph as well, of course. Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of igraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest randomly picking 1000 source nodes, and then for each node run [Breadth-First-Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) until you've visited `k` nodes.  Then, pick the next node that you would visit and set that as the destination for that source.

With this method, you're guaranteed that each destination is reachable from that source.

Comment: Why bother with the BFS?  Just choose a random node as a source, and one of its neighbors as a destination, no need to search.

Comment: @jwpat7 That's the `k = 0` case, right?  BFS gives you a more 'interesting' problem, I think.

Comment: But the problem statement doesn't mention any path lengths, merely requires a path exists.  Having k=0 keeps it simple; given the problem statement, k>0 is a needless complication.

Comment: @jwpat7 Strictly speaking, yes.  But my interpretation of OP is that he wants to be able to run a non-trivial execution of Djikstra's.  Picking neighbors doesn't lead to that.

Comment: I think the discussion here is about bias. Even with `k > 0` there is a bias in the selection of pairs, which may be an issue seeing as the application seems to be data analytics. OP needs to clarify their requirements in terms of the characteristics of the sampling process.

Comment: @Yaniv I agree in principle, although OP doesn't really [seem to have hard requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695432/finding-out-paths-in-a-graph-of-175k-nodes#comment18805340_13695432)

Answer (score 3):

We can use a data-structure like disjoint-union-set(DUS). We do a initialization to get the connectivity of whole graph. If a can reach b, they will located in same set in the DUS. The complexity of the initialization is all depend on the number of edges in the graph. And the query is about O(1).

Comment: That works in an undirected graph, but in a directed graph, `a` can be reachable from `b` while `b` is not reachable from `a`, which I don't think DUS can indicate.

Comment: @SamMussmann Yes, you are right, this algorithm can just work on undirected graph.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm that I suggest:

```
findPairsPath ()
{
    define 2D Array SD //holds source-destination nodes
    SD = {}
    pick any node u randomly
    k=0

    while (k<1000)
    {
       DFS (u, k)
       pick any node u randomly not stored in SD 
    }
}

DFS (u, k)
{

    for all nodes v adjacent to u and not stored in SD
     {
       store (u,v) in SD //storing a source and a destination
       k++
       DFS (v,k)

     }

}
```